# Can't Get The Entire http Response to fit into one String Variable in Kotlin | Android Studio

Tags: android, json, kotlin, https

I am making an http request in Android Studio using the Kotlin programming language to fetch json data like so:

```
try {

        val httpsURL = "https://myUrl&output=JSON"
        val myUrl = URL(httpsURL)
        val conn: HttpsURLConnection = myUrl.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
        val `is`: InputStream = conn.getInputStream()
        val isr = InputStreamReader(`is`)
        val br = BufferedReader(isr)

        var inputLine: String?

        var completeResponse = ""

        while (br.readLine().also { inputLine = it } != null) {

            Log.d("JsonResponse",inputLine)
      
            completeResponse += inputLine
        }

        br.close()

        Log.d("CompleteJson", completeResponse)
}
```

Now the http request works fine, it returns the desired json data - all of it. The problem now is getting all that data into one String variable, completeResponse - from above. What it does is it only Logs a fraction of the response, as if it has been cut or something, how can I make the entire response fit into one string variable ? See Json Data below:

````
    "queryresult":{
        "success":true,
        "error":false,
        "numpods":4,
        "datatypes":"Solve",
        "timedout":"",
        "timedoutpods":"",
        "timing":1.399,
        "parsetiming":0.501,
        "parsetimedout":false,
        "recalculate":"",
        "id":"MSP25021gd4eb281g18f3f300001bgdge9cbch1hf0a",
        "host":"https:\/\/www5b.wolframalpha.com",
        "server":"35",
        "related":"https:\/\/www5b.wolframalpha.com\/api\/v1\/relatedQueries.jsp?id=MSPa25031gd4eb281g18f3f300004agd7ec8e141ce1i1117243612443725456",
        "version":"2.6",
        "pods":[
            {
                "title":"Input interpretation",
                "scanner":"Identity",
                "id":"Input",
                "position":100,
                "error":false,
                "numsubpods":1,
                "subpods":[
                    {
                        "title":"",
                        "img":{
                            "src":"https:\/\/www5b.wolframalpha.com\/Calculate\/MSP\/MSP25041gd4eb281g18f3f300003373653e4dabi6fb?MSPStoreType=image\/gif&s=35",
                            "alt":"solve 2 x - 1 = 1",
                            "title":"solve 2 x - 1 = 1",
                            "width":162,
                            "height":33,
                            "type":"Grid",
                            "themes":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
                            "colorinvertable":true
                        },
                        "plaintext":"solve 2 x - 1 = 1"
                    }
                ],
                "expressiontypes":{
                    "name":"Default"
                }
            },
            {
                "title":"Results",
                "scanner":"Solve",
                "id":"Result",
                "position":200,
                "error":false,
                "numsubpods":2,
                "primary":true,
                "subpods":[
                    {
                        "title":"",
                        "img":{
                            "src":"https:\/\/www5b.wolframalpha.com\/Calculate\/MSP\/MSP25051gd4eb281g18f3f300004gg75d0c168f35ia?MSPStoreType=image\/gif&s=35",
                            "alt":"x = 1",
                            "title":"x = 1",
                            "width":37,
                            "height":19,
                            "type":"Default",
                            "themes":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
                            "colorinvertable":true
                        },
                        "plaintext":"x = 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "title":"Possible intermediate steps",
                        "img":{
                            "src":"https:\/\/www5b.wolframalpha.com\/Calculate\/MSP\/MSP25061gd4eb281g18f3f300002hh389cfc1c98hgb?MSPStoreType=image\/gif&s=35",
                            "alt":"Solve for x:\n2 x - 1 = 1\nAdd 1 to both sides:\n2 x + (1 - 1) = 1 + 1\n1 - 1 = 0:\n2 x = 1 + 1\n1 + 1 = 2:\n2 x = 2\nDivide both sides of 2 x = 2 by 2:\n(2 x)\/2 = 2\/2\n2\/2 = 1:\nx = 2\/2\n2\/2 = 1:\nAnswer: | \n | x = 1",
                            "title":"Solve for x:\n2 x - 1 = 1\nAdd 1 to both sides:\n2 x + (1 - 1) = 1 + 1\n1 - 1 = 0:\n2 x = 1 + 1\n1 + 1 = 2:\n2 x = 2\nDivide both sides of 2 x = 2 by 2:\n(2 x)\/2 = 2\/2\n2\/2 = 1:\nx = 2\/2\n2\/2 = 1:\nAnswer: | \n | x = 1",
                            "width":216,
                            "height":650,
                            "type":"Default",
                            "themes":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
                            "colorinvertable":true
                        },
                        "plaintext":"Solve for x:\n2 x - 1 = 1\nAdd 1 to both sides:\n2 x + (1 - 1) = 1 + 1\n1 - 1 = 0:\n2 x = 1 + 1\n1 + 1 = 2:\n2 x = 2\nDivide both sides of 2 x = 2 by 2:\n(2 x)\/2 = 2\/2\n2\/2 = 1:\nx = 2\/2\n2\/2 = 1:\nAnswer: | \n | x = 1"
                    }
                ],
                "expressiontypes":[
                    {
                        "name":"Default"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"Default"
                    }
                ],
                "states":[
                    {
                        "name":"Hide steps",
                        "input":"Result__Hide steps"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "title":"Plot",
                "scanner":"Solve",
                "id":"RootPlot",
                "position":300,
                "error":false,
                "numsubpods":1,
                "subpods":[
                    {
                        "title":"",
                        "img":{
                            "src":"https:\/\/www5b.wolframalpha.com\/Calculate\/MSP\/MSP25071gd4eb281g18f3f3000020f63b6bia2842d8?MSPStoreType=image\/gif&s=35",
                            "alt":"Plot",
                            "title":"",
                            "width":392,
                            "height":203,
                            "type":"2DMathPlot_1",
                            "themes":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
                            "colorinvertable":true
                        },
                        "plaintext":""
                    }
                ],
                "expressiontypes":{
                    "name":"Default"
                }
            },
            {
                "title":"Number line",
                "scanner":"Solve",
                "id":"NumberLine",
                "position":400,
                "error":false,
                "numsubpods":1,
                "subpods":[
                    {
                        "title":"",
                        "img":{
                            "src":"https:\/\/www5b.wolframalpha.com\/Calculate\/MSP\/MSP25081gd4eb281g18f3f300001dg9f330i4i17c93?MSPStoreType=image\/gif&s=35",
                            "alt":"Number line",
                            "title":"",
                            "width":330,
                            "height":59,
                            "type":"1DMathPlot_1",
                            "themes":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
                            "colorinvertable":true
                        },
                        "plaintext":""
                    }
                ],
                "expressiontypes":{
                    "name":"1DMathPlot"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}```


I want the above JSON data to fit into one string variable called completeResponse, but instead of doing so, it only gets a fraction of the JSON data making it difficult to parse.
````

Comment: How do you know that the returned data is complete? Does logcat show all the lines? How do you know the final content of the variable is incomplete? If you only use logcat to check this maybe it is cut in the output although the variable contains the full string. Maybe you can try to only log the last 50 or so characters from the variable to check where it ends.

Comment: Hi Michael, I know because when I use println() the whole data is printed out, but when I store the response in a string variable not all of it is printed out. And when I try to parse the stored data it says 'cant instantiate with parameters []' showing that something is missing

Comment: This means the shown code (with `Log.d`) doesn't match the code you use for testing. Please show the real code instead.